# Cannot dynamic change CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, backbone.js

I want to do an easy highlight feature in my page.

I create four images, the selected image will become yellow border after I click it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzNmV.jpg

It works on desktop, but it doesn't work when I execute it on Galaxy S3. On Galaxy S3, I click image, the selected image doesn't become yellow immediately. The CSS effect updates until I rotate the device.

By the way, I use jQuery mobile, backboneJS and PhoneGap(Cordova). I'm not sure whether the library causes the problem.

code:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
       initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

            this.render();
       },
       tagName: 'img',
       imgSelected: '',
       events: {
            'click': 'selectImg'
       },
       selectImg: function () {
            $('#picPool img').removeClass('selectedImg');
            this.$el.addClass('selectedImg');
       },
       ...
})
```

Thanks

===============================================================================

Solution:

I try to use touchstart event to replace click event, it works now.

Comment: are you doing any further processing (Javascript) after the click on image?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't affect the images. Even if I comment them, the problem still happen

Comment: First try to check if the problem is _in the CSS_ or _in the JS_ or in the _event triggering_. For the first thing add the `selectedImg` class directly to see if the border appears. For the second try to add/remove another CSS class that you know it works. And for the third add an `alert()` call or something in the event callback.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to use touchstart event to replace click event, it works now.

Comment: Please add your solution as a answer so everybody with the same problem see that there is a solution for this problem.